# запоминание директории fileChooser-ом

Tags: java, javafx

Как в [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) сделать так, чтобы при открытии очередного файла, с помощью `fileChooser`, диалоговое окно выбора файла открывалось в последней директории, где был открыт предыдущий файл? (То есть, чтобы `fileChooser` запоминал директорию последнего файла) написал вот это но при повторном открытии файла(при повторном вызове функции `handleOpen()`) - ругается, консоль вся красная, подскажите, где ошибка

```
String filePathName ="user.home";
@FXML
private void handleOpen() {

      FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

      // Задаём фильтр расширений
      FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
              "PDF files (*.pdf)", "*.pdf");

      fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty(filePathName)));
      // Показываем диалог загрузки файла
      File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());


      if (file != null) {
          filePathName = file.getPath();
          mainApp.loadPDFFromFile(file);
          labelQuantityPage.setText(Integer.toString(mainApp.getQuantityPage()));

      }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

У FileChooser есть специальный метод, который отвечает за [начальную директори](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#setInitialDirectory-java.io.File-). Т.е. вы создаете `FileChooser`, и потом говорите

```
fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File('/path/to/dir'))
```

Соответственно, директорию вы должны сохранять с предыдущего вызова `FileChooser'a`

Comment: а как сохранить директорию с предыдущего вызова? Это нужно как-то через реестр?

Comment: fileChooser.show() возвращает имя файл. Можно взять его парента и сохранить в переменную какую нибудь. И потом уже проставлять эту директорию в вышеописанный метод

Answer (score 1):

В объекте `FileChooser` мы выбираем файл. Получить путь к папке, содержащей файл можно с помощью метода `getParent()`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new 
    File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));

    //...

    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        if (file != null) {
            textArea1.clear();
            //...
            // запоминаем текущий (последний) каталог:
            fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(file.getParent()));
        }
    });

    //...
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]